# Can I use nextUntil to grab these values?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to take the `.text` or `.val` from some `<td>`s that are between `<tr>`s with a class `.ccc` and put it into an array.

```
<tr class="ccc">
   <td>Strategy & Performance</td>
   <td class="l_ccc_data" id="Foo~Q_1"></td> //the innerHTML of this should read 10
   <td class="l_ccc_data" id="Foo~Q_2"></td> //the innerHTML of this should read 12
</tr>
<tr class="inner">
   <td id="Bar~Q_1">5</td>
   <td id="Bar~Q_2">6</td>
</tr>
<tr class="inner">
   <td id="Something~Q_1">5</td>
   <td id="Something~Q_2">6</td>
</tr>
<tr class="ccc">
   <td>Central Engineering</td>
   <td class="l_ccc_data" id="Boo~Q_1">Next total Goes here</td>
   etc...
```

What I have for the script so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.l_ccc_data').each(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var arr_id = id.split('~');
        var q = arr_id[1];
        var arr_sum = [];
        arr_sum.push($(this).nextUntil('.ccc', '[id$="+q+"]').html()); //this could be .text(), or .val(), not sure
        //then add up all the values in arr_sum and set
        //$(this).html(whatever the sum);
    });
});
```

I understand that encoding data into IDs is a bad idea, it's not really able to be helped currently. I need to get the values from any `<td>` that ends with the same Q_1 or Q_2 or whatever as my `<td>` with class `l_ccc_data`. Then I need to get that number, push it to an array, add them up, and have it be displayed in the innerhtml of that `<td>` with class `l_ccc_data`. A simple total. Shouldn't be this hard, but I feel like I'm missing something.

Is this the correct usage of nextUntil? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nextUntil` method will look at the next siblings only, not at the next nodes that might have a different parent.

So you need to go one level up the DOM tree, from the current `td` to the parent `tr`, and then apply `nextUntil`. Then you need to go down again, for which you can use `find`.

Note that there were some errors which I corrected also (for instance the bad quoting in `'[id$="+q+"]'` which made the `+` not function as you intended). Note that you should not use `html()` for putting plain text. Use `text()` for that.

```
$(function(){
    $('.l_ccc_data').each(function(){
        var q = $(this).attr('id').split('~').pop();
        var sum = 0;
        $(this).parent().nextUntil('.ccc').find('[id$="'+q+'"]')
               .each(function () {
                    sum += +$(this).text();
               });
        $(this).text(sum);
    });
});
```

Comment: YES Thank you so much!

Comment: seriously, your explanation was like perfect for me. I didn't know that nextUntil only looked at siblings only. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

A simple `querySelectorAll` call will solve this quite well:

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.ccc > .l_ccc_data');

var texts = Array.prototype.map.call(elements, function(element) {
  return element.innerText;
})

console.log(texts) // ["Total Needs to go here", "Total Needs to go here"]
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="ccc">
    <td>Strategy & Performance</td>
    <td class="l_ccc_data" id="Foo~Q_1">Total Needs to go here</td>
    <td class="l_ccc_data" id="Foo~Q_2">Total Needs to go here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="inner">
    <td id="Bar~Q_1">Some number I need</td>
    <td id="Bar~Q_2">Some number I need</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="inner">
    <td id="Something~Q_1">Some other number I need</td>
    <td id="Something~Q_2">Some number I need</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, I need to get the values of elements with the matching Q value at the end of the ID. Say if it was "Q_1", the array should be [5, 5]. I've clarified in my question.